# The payment was successful, but an error message appeared in the console

Tags: paypal

The payment was successful, but an error message appeared in the console."
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a misconfiguration of the host used for statistics in sandbox mode, and can be ignored.

In general any failure/error from URLs containing 'stats' or 'logger' can be ignored. While not applicable to this case, such consoles errors are sometimes introduced by browsers or extensions that aggressively block trackers, such as ublock origin.